Compiling and running Adonis app with pm2 (typescript)
I finally managed to compile (npx tsc) and execute my Adonis 6 typescript app with pm2:

When I check with pm2 list looks like everything is ok:

However, checking logs I see this error:

I am using typescript, so what I have is env.ts file and not env.js.
Here is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "@adonisjs/tsconfig/tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "types": ["@adonisjs/auth"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src"
  ]
}

How can I indicate compiler to use this file? Is there any other things I need to have in account compiling typescript?

show the content of 'tsconfig.json'. There might be somthing wrong with the config.

Just added it, thanks!

'./start' is not included

for prod environment, just copy .env into dist folder
